# How does reload handle library files as `so`

Tags: python, openssl, pip, python-requests

I've installed a user module with the command `pip --ignore-installed --user requests[security]` and realized that the python interpreter, which is embedded in a tool, is ignoring that and is loading first the System wide installed Module i:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL
```

So went ahead and inserted manually my user path and tried to reload every module in `OpenSSL` like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, /Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/)
reload(OpenSSL.SSL)
reload(OpenSSL.SSL)
reload(OpenSSL._util)
reload(OpenSSL.crypto)
reload(OpenSSL.rand)
reload(OpenSSL.version)
```

However, I've realized that that `OpenSSL` comes with `so` files. Is reload reloading `so` files as well?

Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html?highlight=reload#imp.reload

> There are a number of other caveats:
>
> It is legal though generally **not very useful to reload built-in or dynamically loaded modules**, except for sys, __main__ and builtins. In many cases, however, **extension modules are not designed to be initialized more than once**, and may fail in arbitrary ways when reloaded.

(Emphasize mine — phd.)